# Redirecting to login page to unauthorized user yii

Tags: yii

**access rules of pages controller:**

```
public function accessRules()
{                   
    $isadmin = User::loadUser(Yii::app()->user->id)->adminUser;

    return array(
            array('allow', 
                    'actions'=>array('index','view','create','update'),
                    'expression'=>"{$isadmin}==1",
                    ),
          array('deny',  // deny all users
                'users'=>array('*'),
            ),          

    );
}
```

**main config:**

```
 'user' => array(         // Webuser for the admin area (admin)
        'class'             => 'WebUser',
        'allowAutoLogin' => true,
        'loginUrl'          => array('/user/login'),
        'stateKeyPrefix'    => 'admin_',
    ),
```

**Problem:**
When I visit pages/create, it not redirected to user/login but throws the exception:

```
Error 404

The requested page does not exist.
```

How Can I redirect to login pages for unauthorized user?

Answer (score 2):

You can use 'deniedCallback' to do this.

**Method 1**

```
      'deniedCallback' => function() {Yii::app()->controller->redirect(array ('actionName'));},

      //It will come As

       array('allow',                
            'actions' => array('actionName1,actionName2,actionName3'),
            'deniedCallback' => function() {Yii::app()->controller->redirect(array ('actionName'));},
            'users' => array('@'),
        ),
```

**Method 2:**
You can also do the same by calling a function, see bellow code.

```
        array('allow',
            'deniedCallback' => array($this, 'goToLogin'),
            'actions' => array('actionName1,actionName2,actionName3'),
            'users' => array('@'),
        ),
```

Code for **goToLogin** method

```
        public function goToLogin()
        {
             $this->redirect('/controller/actionName');
             //For your program 
             //$this->redirect('/site/login');
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Yii::app()->user->loginRequired();

Answer (score 0):

add this funtion in every controller.

```
public function beforeAction($action) {

if (Yii::app()->user->isGuest && Yii::app()->controller->action->id != "login") {
    Yii::app()->user->loginRequired();
}
//something code right here if user valid
return true;  
}
```

site controller only needs **Yii::app()->controller->action->id != "login"** this condition. remove it for another controllers